# Can't get a basic method to work

Tags: java, class, methods

Can anyone please tell why the getSpeed method does not work ?

Whenever I hover over the method I get the :

to insert ;
illegal modifier
syntax error please insert []
syntax error on token

```
public class Tanks {

private String TankName;
private int TankModel;
private int CrewNumber;
private double Speed;
private int TurretSpeed;


Tanks (String name, int model, int crew, double speed, int turretspeed){

    this.TankName = name;
    this.TankModel = model;
    this.CrewNumber = crew;
    this.Speed = speed;
    this.TurretSpeed = turretspeed;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tanks merkava = new Tanks ("MERKAVA", 1, 5, 56.64, 67);
    Tanks judge = new Tanks ("JUDGE", 2, 6, 66.66, 68); 


    public double getSpeed() {
        return Speed;
    }

    System.out.println(merkava.TankName+ " "+merkava.TankModel+" "+merkava.CrewNumber+" "+merkava.Speed+" "+merkava.TurretSpeed);
    System.out.println(judge.TankName+ " "+judge.TankModel+" "+judge.CrewNumber+" "+judge.Speed+" "+judge.TurretSpeed);

} 
}
```

Comment: You don't declare methods inside other methods' bodies.

Comment: also, you try to access private attributes directly in those println. You need to use accessors.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you can't declare one method inside another, you're never actually calling the `getSpeed` method.

Answer (score 4):

Your `main` method contains the following method.

```
 public double getSpeed() {
        return Speed;
    }
```

Please move this to `Tanks` class.

Following should work:

```
public class Tanks {

private String TankName;
private int TankModel;
private int CrewNumber;
private double Speed;
private int TurretSpeed;

Tanks(String name, int model, int crew, double speed, int turretspeed) {

    this.TankName = name;
    this.TankModel = model;
    this.CrewNumber = crew;
    this.Speed = speed;
    this.TurretSpeed = turretspeed;

}

public double getSpeed() {
    return Speed;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tanks merkava = new Tanks("MERKAVA", 1, 5, 56.64, 67);
    Tanks judge = new Tanks("JUDGE", 2, 6, 66.66, 68);

    System.out.println(merkava.TankName + " " + merkava.TankModel + " " + merkava.CrewNumber + " " + merkava.Speed
            + " " + merkava.TurretSpeed);
    System.out.println(judge.TankName + " " + judge.TankModel + " " + judge.CrewNumber + " " + judge.Speed + " "
            + judge.TurretSpeed);

}
}
```

Comment: I moved it no more errors, but no answer just the ones from the 2 System.out.println

Comment: Attributes are private. They should be called through accessors in those println

Comment: @lupul666 what did you expect apart from the two `print` statements.

Comment: I'm getting following `o/p`
`MERKAVA 1 5 56.64 67`
`JUDGE 2 6 66.66 68`

Comment: I think its printing speed, no?

Comment: i thought that   the method would also do that :S                                                                              
 public double getSpeed() {
        return Speed;
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you have gone through some basic `Java` course you will know that by defining a method (in this case `getSpeed()`) inside another function (`main`) is wrong.